# How to make my HTML website fit to screen using Dreamweaver?

Tags: html, web, dreamweaver

I've designed & converted a webpage from Photoshop to Dreamweaver. My document pixels is 1000*1600. I need to make the page's width to fit to the screen in the browser. I tried adding width="100%" in the body tag. Please give some ideas.

Comment: You should add to the question the (simplified) html of your page; without it, it would be very difficult for anyone to help you (you can find advice on how to write a good question in the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)).

Answer (score 0):

It's quite hard to help you since we've no reference code to take a look at.

Since ur saying you've used width="100%", I assume you've added this to the body-element in HTML.

You can try the following:

**Option 1:** If you are using a seperate CSS file:

```
body{
    width: 100%;
    /* other css options here */
}
```

**Option 2:** If you are using the HTML file for markup, add the following between the head element:

```
<head>
   <style>
      body{
         width: 100%;
         /* other css options here */
      }
   </style>
</head>
```

Please let me know if this worked out for you.